# onclick simple function with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create simple function that will work two ways. Basically, when I click on `.slideme` once it will add a class, and when I click second time it will remove that class.

I have this:

```
 $(".slideme").click(function() {
     $('#login').addClass("green");
   },function(){
     $('#login').removeClass("green");
   });
```

Unfortunately it works only half way; when I click the second time nothing happens.

How can I solve this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [*toggleClass*](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/):

```
$(".slideme").click(function() {
    $('#login').toggleClass("green");
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/ZQfeW/